# RDD Unique ID during whole processing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, rdd

My stream flow is:

KafkaDirectStream -> mapPartitions -> foreachRDD -- foreachPartition

I need to identify RDDs uniquly from KafkaDirectStream  to foreachPartition. Is there a way to uniquely identify RDDs during whole processing of streaming job? I have tried using id() and setName()/name() methods but they are not sustained from receiver to foreachRDD?

Comment: What would you want to achieve with that?? Maybe there's another way.

Comment: I have been trying hard to manage Kafka offsets but getting 

     ...is being serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation. This is because the DStream object is being referred to from within the closure. Please rewrite the RDD operation inside this DStream to avoid this. This has been enforced to avoid bloating of Spark tasks with unnecessary objects

Comment: That's why I decided to use AtomicReference<Map> to manage offsets

Comment: could you add your code? this error " ...is being serialized possibly as a part of closure of an RDD operation" is a nested DStream or  RDD operation. I still don't get the gist of the question. Do you want the ID of the RDD to track offsets?

Comment: Whole code is quite verbose. Code structure I tried for managing the offsets is as follows:
KafkaDirectStream -> foreachRDD -- foreachPartition

I have trying to get offsets in foreachRDD.call() using the code: OffsetRange[] offsets = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

But was always getting this exception. I know offsets must be gotten in immediate transformation/action. 

Because of this problem, I am planning to use RDD Unique ID to manage offsets.

Comment: I think you're on the wrong path. You can obtain the offsets at the very start, from the kafkaDirectStream, store then in a temporary variable, and commit them at the end of your process. Trying to track back RDDs is going to give you headaches, but if you must, each RDD has a reference to its parent(s). See `rdd.firstParent`

Comment: May be, you're right, in the beginning, I was trying the same. Can you please refer to some example? I found a few but I would love the one you recommend.

Comment: @maasg Please also clarify about 2 points. 1. What if data is committed in some partitions and process breaks. 2. By end of process, you mean after foreachRDD (outside of it)?